# .webp image not shown on website hosted on godaddy's plesk

Tags: laravel, plesk

The images having .webp format are not shown on website.  all other format images in that folder are accessible  but only the .webp format is not accessible. Using URL if try to access it redirects to 404 page as the file format is not supported.

The webp images are work properly on cpanel. but not worked on plesk why is it so?
Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends of your navigator, WebP format is fairly new and not widely supported.

You can check the currently supporting browsers @ https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp

Check also that your server return the right mimeType. For apache add this line to the `.htaccess`

```
AddType image/webp .webp
```

Answer (score 0):

**GoDaddy *shared hosting* does not support webp and other formats** when using those newer image types on their IIS/PLESK server platforms. If you want WebP support you have to move up to their expensive dedicated hosting platform as PLESK and IIs on shared hosting does not have the added WebP MIME type added on their servers. Nor can you add it, as far as I know. If there is a way to access this feature from PLESK, it would be possible. The only fix you can try is adding a custom "web.config" with this MIME type added. Upload this to a folder in your website where a file is accessing the image type. Your site must have Microsoft ASP.NET installed and running.